# ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit. .POST_MODULE

Tags: java, spring, wildfly

Help!
I want deployed im have this error:

> 22:50:45,854 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./opciondefensa.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./opciondefensa.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet from [Module "deployment.opciondefensa.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1066)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:281)
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet from [Module "deployment.opciondefensa.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:721)
>       ... 6 more

22:50:45,860 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "opciondefensa.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./opciondefensa.UndertowDeploymentInfoService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./opciondefensa.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet from [Module \"deployment.opciondefensa.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet from [Module \"deployment.opciondefensa.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}

---

**

> MY POM BELOW follow the same trouble.

**

---

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>cl.legal</groupId>
  <artifactId>opciondefensa</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>opciondefensa Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <tiles.version>3.0.1</tiles.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
        <logback.version>0.9.26</logback.version>
        <postgresql.version>9.4.1208</postgresql.version>
        <javax.version>3.1.0</javax.version>
        <jsp.version>2.1</jsp.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<!--     SERVLET  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsp.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<!--    JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<!--    SPRING FRAMEWORK -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>         
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
              <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
              <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
        </exclusions>   
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
              <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
              <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
        </exclusions>   
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>         
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>                     
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
              <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
              <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
<!--    <dependency> -->
<!--          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> -->
<!--          <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId> -->
<!--          <version>${spring.version}</version> -->
<!--          <scope>provided</scope> -->
<!--      </dependency> -->

<!--    ORM HIBERNATE [JPA] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
<!--    <dependency> -->
<!--       <groupId>dom4j</groupId> -->
<!--       <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId> -->
<!--       <version>1.6.1</version> -->
<!--       <scope>provided</scope> -->
<!--    </dependency> -->
<!--  postgres  Connector-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<!-- Tiles -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>        
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>

<!--    Log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>opciondefensa</finalName>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                  <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                  <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What about your code?

Comment: don´t writing many coding, only configuring project by starting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is clear

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
```

you try to use spring but you are not including it to your war.

see what jars are included in your `opciondefensa.war`

Why is `spring-mvc` of scope `provided`?

Comment: revisaré thanks!!, pero si no los tuviera como los agrego?

Comment: i dont understand. if this helped you please accept my answer and write your question in english :)

Comment: Ok, dont talk in english perfectly sorry, other thing i had format my pc... i had a little in that... still have that to revisit.

Comment: Follow my trouble, dont now why... buuu!!

Comment: @user6558875 please remove scope provided from spring-mvc dependency

Comment: please accept (and upvote if you want) the answer in order for this question to be considered closed. thank you!

Comment: thanks! is working now, I remove all scope provided and also update 
http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/neon/4.4.0.Final.html , I worked so.

Comment: be careful with scopes. :)

Comment: Ok, I´ll see what happens. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this,

> right-click on the project -> properties -> deployment assembly -> add
>   -> java buildpath entries -> select maven build path library -> apply -> ok.

I hope it will resolve your issue.